# pandas column split with condition

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas column / series has mixed datatype. When I split based on delimiter `-`, the cells containing datatype `int` are set to `NaN`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'val': [1000, "1000-1200", 1400, "1500-1600"] })

df.val.str.split('-').str[0]

0     NaN
1    1000
2     NaN
3    1500
Name: val, dtype: object
```

I'd like to retain the `ints` values and not set them `NaN`. The expected output is below:

```
0    1000
1    1000
2    1400
3    1500
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

fillna:

```
df.val.str.split('-').str[0].fillna(df['val'])
```